# Rails 4 configuring the asset host with a sub directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can the asset host be configured to have a subdirectory in the URL? Like

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "myassets.mybiz.com/my/app/name/and/some/more/"
```

And, if the server at `myassets.mybiz.com` is running the rails app, can it be configured to strip the directory prefix (`my/app/name/and/some/more/`) before searching the asset path? So that, `my/app/name/and/some/more/my_image.png` will be found in the rails public dir at `public/my_image.png`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I cannot remember. It would take me some time to dig up that code and see what I did. How important is it to you?

Comment: No worries, I may post an answer when I eventually finish solving it, but I'm working on some other stuff now